# React-native-paper: Как переключить состояние кнопки?

Tags: react-native

У меня есть две кнопки "yes" и "no". Когда нажимаешь на кнопку "yes" должен появиться дополнительный контент. Застопорилась с переключением кнопок. У активной кнопке должен меняться фон и цвет текста. То-есть когда нажимаешь на кнопку ДА она должна стать синей и появиться контент, но если нажать потом кнопку НЕТ то дополнительный контент должен пропасть и активной стать кнопка НЕТ (поменять цвет фона). Я только начала делать что-то прод React и у меня еще много чего не выходит
Вот мой код:

```
i mport React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Appbar, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper'    
import colors from '../constants/colors'

const MyScreen = () => {

const onOtherInsurance = () => {
    console.log(' onThisInsurance pressed')
    setActive(true)
  }

  const onThisInsurance = () => {
    console.log(' onThisInsurance pressed')
    setСhecked(true)
  }

  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [checked, setСhecked] = useState(false);

return (
......
 <View style={[styles.row]}>
        <Button color={[active ? colors.WHITE:  colors.TEXT_TOTAL_GREY]}
          style={[active ? styles.buttonActive :styles.button]}
          onPress={onOtherInsurance}>YES</Button>
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.top_space, styles.row]}>
        <Button color={[checked ? colors.WHITE:  colors.TEXT_TOTAL_GREY]}
          style={[checked ? styles.buttonActive :styles.button]}
          onPress={onThisInsurance}>NO</Button>
      </View>
      {active ? <View style={styles.containerInput}>
        <TextInput
          label="Tell us more about it"
          multiline={true}
          autoFocus={true}
          theme={{
            roundness: 4
          }}
          style={styles.diagnosis}
          mode='flat'
          value={state.name}
          onChangeText={text => setState({ ...state, name: text })}
        />
      </View> : ''
      }
 );
}
```

Comment: непонятно зачем checked, если достаточно одного active. И на второй кнопке вставить ее в условие и на клик ставить в false

Comment: Мне нужно, чтоб кнопка НЕТ тоже была как бы активной и меняла цвет в то время как другая становилась не активной. Если я поставлю active  в false на клик кнопки НЕТ то кнопка будет не активной. Или я ошибаюсь?